# Konsole does not run shell specified in /etc/passwd

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh, konsole

I've been using Bash for a long time on Fedora with Gnome, and recently switched to Arch Linux, Plasma and ZSH. I set up zsh, file, used `chsh -s $(which zsh)`, and it works. However, every time I run Konsole bash runs automatically, and I have to manually call `zsh`. This is what I do know:

`echo $SHELL` returns /bin/bash

`cat /etc/passwd | grep $LOGNAME` shows my shells as /usr/bin/zsh

When I log in on a tty (no graphical), ZSH runs by default.

Update 1: The "Preferences/Configure/General" tab does not have a "Command" option, and there is no GUI option in User settings that has to do with my shell.

Comment: Did you restart KDE since changing your shell?

Comment: Just now, and now it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

See `Settings>Configure Konsole>Profiles`.

Edit the relevant profile and change the `Command` field.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see, KDE and Konsole *should* respect the default option. To enforce that you can use this little script:

> $ sudo vi /usr/local/bin/shell.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

PSHELL=$(getent passwd $USER|cut -d: -f7)

eval "$PSHELL"
```

Allow it to run with:

> $ sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/shell.sh

Then go to your *Konsole* profile

`Settings>Configure Konsole>Profiles>Edit Profile>General Tab>Command`

Change `/bin/bash` to `/usr/local/bin/shell.sh`

From now on, if you use `chsh -s /bin/someshell`, *Konsole* will respect your choice.

To see the shells available to you use:

`cat /etc/shells`

> Sample output:

```
# /etc/shells: valid login shells
/bin/sh
/bin/bash
/usr/bin/bash
/bin/rbash
/usr/bin/rbash
/bin/dash
/usr/bin/dash
/usr/bin/tmux
/bin/zsh
/usr/bin/zsh
```

---

Note 1: it is not recommended to add `shell.sh` in `/etc/shells`. Let it be just for *Konsole* config.

Note 2: You can save it in a different folder if you prefer. For example, if you have only one user, a good place would be `~/bin/shell.sh` and now you don't even need sudo.

Comment: great idea, but it appears not to propagate the "login" attribute, which is conveyed by setting argv[0] to start with a '-'.

Comment: "konsole" is a KDE application, and I don't think it can be used as login shell.